# Mutiselection in treeview silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, treeview

How can i enable multi selection in silverlight treeview controll?

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try adding the checkbox to the treeview item to enable multiple selection.

If you have installed Toolkit in your machine then you can find the Treeview checkbox sample there C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\Apr10\Samples\defaul t.htm